# Accessing serial data on USB COM port

Tags: c#, io

I have a h/w device connected to my USB port. The device sends serial data to my USB port. It is connected on one of the COM ports.

I wanted to know, how can I take these values in a C# desktop client?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for that .Net 2.0 component [SerialPort Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

Comment: No he can't. USB ports are not Serial Ports.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me why can't I do that? USB sends serial data, right?

Comment: Yes, you can, most COM ports nowadays are done through USB, they appear as regular old COM ports.